# Aligning overbraces with other TikZ tree nodes

Tags: math-mode, alignment, math-operators, tikz-qtree, overbrace

I'm using the `tikz-qtree` package to create a tree. Using `\overbrace` in a node changes the height of the node, but the anchor does not align with it. Using `\underbrace` works perfectly fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
Aligned:

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=0.5cm,
    level distance=1.5cm,
    growth parent anchor={north},
    nodes={anchor=north},
    empty/.style={draw=none},
    ptredlabel/.style={pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}}]
\Tree
    [.{\color{red} $\underbrace{\color{black} (\lnot (p \wedge q) \wedge r_3)}_{\textrm{(5b) }(\alpha \wedge \beta)}$}
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=right] {$\alpha$};
        [.{$\color{red}\underbrace{\color{black}\lnot (p \wedge q)}_{\textrm{(5a) }\lnot \alpha}$}
        [.{$\lnot$} ]
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\alpha$};
        [.{$\color{red}\underbrace{\color{black}(p \wedge q)}_{\textrm{(5b) } (\alpha \wedge \beta)}$}
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=right] {$\alpha$};
        [.{p} ]
            \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\beta$};
            [.{q} ]
        ]
    ]
    \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\beta$};
    [.{$r_3$} ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

Not aligned:

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=0.5cm,
    level distance=1.5cm,
    growth parent anchor={north},
    nodes={anchor=north},
    empty/.style={draw=none},
    ptredlabel/.style={pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}}]
\Tree
    [.{\color{red} $\overbrace{\color{black} (\lnot (p \wedge q) \wedge r_3)}^{\textrm{(5b) }(\alpha \wedge \beta)}$}
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=right] {$\alpha$};
        [.{$\color{red}\overbrace{\color{black}\lnot (p \wedge q)}^{\textrm{(5a) }\lnot \alpha}$}
        [.{$\lnot$} ]
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\alpha$};
        [.{$\color{red}\overbrace{\color{black}(p \wedge q)}^{\textrm{(5b) } (\alpha \wedge \beta)}$}
        \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=right] {$\alpha$};
        [.{p} ]
            \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\beta$};
            [.{q} ]
        ]
    ]
    \edge node[ptredlabel,auto=left] {$\beta$};
    [.{$r_3$} ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Using \underbrace works, \overbrace does not.]

Is it possible to make this work with `\overbrace` so that the anchors of the nodes are on the same level?

Comment: I'd recommend `forest`. (Depending on your needs, even `prooftrees`, but I suspect you don't need that here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `forest` is an option, this is fairly straightforward and can be semi-automated using a technique illustrated in the manual (and featured in lots of answers on this site).

[image: with nodes aligned at top]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  sn edges,
  ptredlabel/.style n args=3{% adapted from Forest manual page 84
    edge label/.expanded={node[pos=.5,ptredlabelfont,text=red!70!black,auto=#1,anchor=#2]{\strut$\unexpanded{#3}$}}},
  /tikz/ptredlabelfont/.style={font=\footnotesize},
  ptredlabelaux/.style={if n=1{ptredlabel={left}{east}{#1}}{ptredlabel={right}{west}{#1}}},
  for tree={math content, anchor=north},
  delay={
    for descendants={split option={content}{:}{content,ptredlabelaux}},
  },
  [\overbrace{\color{black} (\lnot (p \wedge q) \wedge r_3)}^{\textrm{(5b) }(\alpha \wedge \beta)}, red
    [\overbrace{\color{black}\lnot (p \wedge q)}^{\textrm{(5a) }\lnot \alpha}:\alpha, red
      [\lnot]
      [\overbrace{\color{black}(p \wedge q)}^{\textrm{(5b) } (\alpha \wedge \beta)}:\alpha, red
        [p:\alpha]
        [q:\beta]
      ]
    ]
    [r_3:\beta]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```